# How can we automate the login process into IBM Kubernetes Service(IKS)?

Tags: kubernetes, ibm-cloud, iks, login-automation

We need some scripts or some way that can help us to automate our login into the IBM kubernetes cluster so that we don't have to do it manually everytime and can keep running automation scripts into the pipeline.
We already have a cluster on IBM cloud with three worker nodes. And, we are trying to perform some automation on the same.

Please help if you have any idea regarding the same.

Comment: What do you mean with "login"? Do you already have access to IBM Cloud, do you have an API key available, what action do you want to perform? Add more details

Comment: Yeah, we do have access to IBM cloud and we need the automated login so that we can keep running our scripts in the pipeline... but are not sure about how we can achieve that

Comment: You can log in to IBM Cloud using userid / password, or with an API key or auth token - the last are available for service IDs, too. Plenty of options and that is how automation is using it

Answer (score 1):

given the fact that your question is pretty vague and sincerely I am not shore  short answer would be to use something like openshift. Here is an article that might help you:

https://www.openshift.com/blog/enhancing-the-openshift-web-console-login-experience